# DHCP lease acquired , yet no ping, not even to default gateway

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, internet

I've just installed Debian Wheezy on my PC using netinstall.

I can only use its wifi. My interface has been recognize by the system, and I've used:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid MY_HOME_AP
```

(I've switched off router's security in order to ease the pain of getting a first connection to the internet)

then I used:

```
dhclient wlan0 -v
```

to get an IP address. I now have a valid local IP. I can also see it on my router DHCP clients list.

However, I can't ping anywhere, not even the default gateway.

My routing tables is:

```
default  192.168.2.1 0.0.0.0       UG 0 0 0 wlan0
localnet *           255.255.255.0 U  0 0 0 wlan0
```

where do I have it wrong?

**ADDED:**
1. The entire output of 'netstat -rn' is attached above.
2. the output of 'ifconfig' (copied by hand..):

```
wlan0 Link  encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1f:1f:a6:29:ba
      inet  addr:192.168.2.101 Bcast:192.168.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21f:1fff:fea6:32da/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
      RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0  txquelen:1000
      RX bytes:18334 (17.9 KiB) TX bytes:4172 (4.0 KiB)
```

Comment: Please provide the complete output of `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig`.

Comment: @KyleJones added.

Comment: *I've switched off router's security* - it sounds like maybe the router has more switched off than that, like maybe it's not doing any routing, or it has no route to 192.168.2.101 .  Can you use another computer to check this - try one that was previously working with your router.

Comment: I have many other devices using this router as gateway , both windows and linux variants @BruceEdiger

Comment: @BruceEdiger btw, by switching off security I meant not using WEP/WPA .